# Python Boto3 AWS DynamoDB get item from table without sort key

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to update an item from my DynamoDb table from a AWS Lambda function and I am getting the following error:

> "errorMessage": "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: The provided key element does not match the schema",

I have not defined a sort key when defining my table, and my partition key is named 'pipeId', and I have used the following code:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('mytable')

response = table.update_item(
    Key={
        'pipeId': pipe_id
        },
    UpdateExpression="set hookId = :r",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':r': hook_id
        },
    ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
)
```

Isn't possible to get or update an item without previously setting a sort key ? or am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: I don't see anything about sort key in the error message, so not sure why you are focusing on that. It is saying that `pipeId` is not actually the primary key of your table. Are you sure it's not `PipeID` or `pipe_id` or something?

Comment: I was focusing on that because I saw many other topics pointing that this error was because they were providing an incomplete key; And yes, I am using the right table name. @MarkB  thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution.

The problem was that my primary key is defined as number and I was  inserting it as  String, like "3219"; but it doesn't convert automatically.

Comment: Your Solution woks for me, Thanks for question here